# UWP - Application does not relaunch normally using CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync(string.Empty)

Tags: uwp

When I use the method: `CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync(string.Empty)` my 
UWP app's window closes but does not activates. Then I cannot show app's window when click app's icon on taskbar. But it restarts perfectly in older version, and I'm sure I don't edit this code in new version. I don't know why, my current windows version is 1809.

Comment: I could reproduce this issue. I've reported to the relevant team. Thanks for your feedback. If possible, you also could report this issue in our Feedback Hub.

Comment: Same problem here. Is there a link to the reported issue?

Comment: What's the result you get when calling `RequestRestartAsync` function? And also, how do you launch/start the app in the first place? According to official documentation, this might be related - see the Remarks section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.requestrestartasync?view=winrt-19041